# Configure Visual Studio Code to compile Project on F7 key

Tags: compilation, onclick, task, visual-studio-code, hotkeys

I am trying to configure Visual Studio Code (VSC) to compile Project on <kbd>F7</kbd> key. Unfortunately, this IDE does not have a GUI for editing settings like LiteIDE.

I have done the following:

1. opened a 'hello.go' file in VSC.
2. pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> as mentioned on MS's page.
3. searched for 'Other' in the list and have not found it.
4. (?) How I am supposed to use 'Other tasks' which they told me to select?
5. ok, now I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and it says:

   > "No build task defined. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand' in the tasks.json file."
6. I press blue button "Configure build task". It creates folder ".vscode" in my working directory and 'tasks.json' file inside it.
7. 'What the hell are you doing?' - I think. don't make mess in my folder. it is for source files! not for microsoft. ok. let us imagine that we decided to agree with mess in working folder.
8. in the suggested template, I modify some text and have following 'tasks.json' in the end:

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "go build",
       "taskName": "goBuild",
       "isShellCommand": true,
       "args": [""],
       "showOutput": "always"
   }
   ```
9. (?) I save the file and try to show list of actions again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. I do not see my task in the list. VSC restart does not help. hm.... why is it not in the list?
10. maybe keybindings will work as I want? File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts (I am not a maniac to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, who has created such double hot-..oh..no..it is cold-keys already! XD ).
11. I click the link to edit .json file manually and add:

    ```
     // Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
    [{
        "key": "f7",
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.goBuild",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }]
    ```
12. save, push <kbd>F7</kbd> in editor and... 
    `command 'workbench.action.tasks.goBuild' not found`

After using LiteIDE for Go language, in which everything was with 1 click (1 button to build), it seems as VSC was created by aliens for aliens... not for humans as me, at least :(

Answer (score 0):

i'm posting here bc i first tried a visual studio shortcuts for vscode, which didn't include most basic commands.

never understood why microsoft decided to change all defaults for vscode, but if you want to have F7=build, F8=build solution, f5=run, etc...

it's easier than ever to do... just use the built-it keyboard shortcut editor at file -> preferencces -> keyboard

[more information and screenshots here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)